# Kotlin: How do I add an actionbar menu on a tabbed activity?

Tags: kotlin, android-actionbar, fragment

I have a tabbed activity with fragments. Now I just need to add an actionbar menu. I am guessing I add the action bar in the mainactivity. How can I do this?

I have tried adding an action bar for each fragment but looks like that cannot be done in kotlin. I am new to android development but I was able to perform this task with java. I am converting my small projects to Kotlin which is supposed to be easier than java.

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    val sectionsPagerAdapter = SectionsPagerAdapter(this, supportFragmentManager)
    val viewPager: ViewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager)
    viewPager.adapter = sectionsPagerAdapter
    val tabs: TabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabs)
    tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)
    val fab: FloatingActionButton = findViewById(R.id.fab)


    fab.setOnClickListener { view ->
        Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
            .setAction("Action", null).show()
    }

    fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.mainmenu, menu)
        return true
    }


}
```

}

Comment: How did you do it in Java? It shouldn't be any different in Kotlin except for syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Actually figured it out. My question was basically senseless. It should have been how to add a menu in an AppBarLayout. My app is using a tabbed activity.

All I had to do was under my main activity layout, I needed to add a toolbar under the Appbarlayout.

then under the Main activity Oncreate, I added

`setSupportActionBar(toolbar)` 
 `val actionBar = supportActionBar`

Then call the oncreateoptionsmenu

`override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
    // Inflate the menu to use in the action bar
    val inflater = menuInflater
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.mainmenu, menu)
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
}`